# INSERT or on duplicate KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a populated input fields with data from mysql table called `person`. I am able to store data in the table or update the data in table. Now I am trying to accomplish doing both in one query;  `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;`. The values share a foreign key called `academy_id` so In order to update each value I have to also specify the unique auto increment id called `person_id`. When I perform a query I get error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use`. How can I fix that and be able to Insert new values or update current values? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/select_test.php)

SELECT Query to display values from table

```
//SELECT Query to display values
$id = 15; 
$db_select3  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT     a.name, 
           a.academy_id,
           p.person_id,
           p.first_name,
           p.last_name
    FROM academy a
    LEFT JOIN person p ON a.academy_id = p.academy_id
    WHERE a.academy_id = :id
");
if (!$db_select3) return false;
if (!$db_select3->execute(array(':id' => $id))) return false;
    $results3 = $db_select3->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results3)) return false;
    $result3 = '';
echo "<strong>Personel Information:</strong>";
$s = 1;
foreach ($results3 as $value3){ 
    echo "<ul id=\"pq_entry_".$s."\" class=\"clonedSection\">";
    echo "Primary AI Key ID <b>person_id</b>: " . $value3['person_id'] . "</br>";
    echo "Foreign Key ID <b>academy_id</b>: " . $value3['academy_id'] . "</br>";
    echo "<li><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"person_id_".$s."\" value='". $person_id = $value3['person_id']."'/></li>";
    echo "<li><input id=\"person_fname_".$s."\" name=\"person_fname_".$s."\" placeholder=\"Person #1 - First Name\" type=\"text\" value='" . $value3['first_name'] ."'/><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"person_id_".$s."\" value='". $person_id = $value2['person_id']."'/></li>";
    echo "<li><input id=\"person_lname_".$s."\" name=\"person_lname_".$s."\" placeholder=\"Last Name\" type=\"text\" value='" . $value3['last_name'] ."'/></li>";
    echo "</ul>";
$s++;   
}   
echo "<input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add another Person' />
<input type='button' id='btnDel' value='Delete' /></br>";
```

INSERT/UPDATE Query

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //Insert or Update Values 
        $f = 1;
        while(isset($_POST['person_fname_' . $f]))
        {

            $person_fname = $_POST['person_fname_' . $f];
            $person_lname = $_POST['person_lname_' . $f];

            $query_init3 = "INSERT INTO person (academy_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:id,:person_fname,:person_lname) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE person SET academy_id=:id, first_name=:person_fname, last_name=:person_lname WHERE academy_id=:id AND person_id=:person_id;";
            $query_prep3 = $db_con->prepare($query_init3);
            $query_prep3->execute(array(
                "id" => $id,
                "person_id" => $person_id,
                "person_fname" => $person_fname,
                "person_lname" => $person_lname
            ));

            $f++;
        }
}
```

Table Values:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| person_id | academy_id | first_name  | last_name |  
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|        1  |         15 | James       | Barkley   |  
|        2  |         15 | Cynthia     | Smith     |  
|        3  |          8 | Peter       | Black     |  
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: One error is that there's a duplicate `UPDATE` in your code. (Near `$query_init3 = `.)

Comment: How many unique constraints do you have on the table? Just `academy_id`?

Comment: @Jack The only unique constraint is `people_id` added a table modeler so it makes more sense

Comment: Then why is `person_id` not present in the `insert` statement? Wouldn't that be a requirement?

Comment: @Jack `person_id` is an `auto_increment` field in the table

Comment: In that case you won't be able to get unique constraint issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify the WHERE condition because you already used the clause on UPDATE.

Try:

```
$query_init3 = "INSERT INTO person (academy_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:id,:person_fname,:person_lname) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE academy_id=:id, first_name=:person_fname, last_name=:person_lname";
```

Comment: Alright this worked, it seems best that i should delete the values and then re insert. I have `$query_init3 = "DELETE FROM person WHERE academy_id=:id  INSERT INTO person (academy_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:id,:person_fname,:person_lname);";` but it shows syntax error as well. How can I correct that as well? You can check the example [LINK](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/select_test.php)

Comment: Well run it query by query, here you are trying to run two queries in one shoot. Also you missed the semi column before the INSERT INTO.